# Rewrite Rule not taking effect

Tags: url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite some URLs using my .htaccess file and the following syntax:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^movie/([0-9]+)/$ movie.php?id=$1
```

Basically, the URL `http://screeningapp.co.uk/movie.php?id=771316320` should be rewritten to `http://screeningapp.co.uk/movie/771316320`, but that's not happening and I'm not sure why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^movie/([0-9]+)/?$ /movie.php?id=$1 [L,nc]

#if you wanna redirect movie.php?id=1 to movie/1/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^movie.php$ /movie/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this would suddenly stop working? It worked fine in the first instance, and I've just gone to another page with the same URL format and it's not working. Similarly, it's now not working on the page which I tested it on originally.

Comment: try to clear your browser cache (or replace R=301 with R=302) and see if it works.